# String in do while loop

Tags: c

```
// PigLatinFinal.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void Heading (void)
{
    printf("************************************************************\n");
    printf("*                        Pig Latin                         *\n");
    printf("*                                                          *\n");
    printf("*                                                          *\n");
    printf("*                     Welcome                              *\n");
    printf("*                                                          *\n");
    printf("* In this program, the user will enter a word in English   *\n");
    printf("* The program will then return the word in Pig Latin.      *\n");
    printf("* The word cannot be longer than 7 letters.  You can       *\n");
    printf("* translate as many words as you wish. Enter 'END' without *\n");
    printf("* the quotation marks to end the program. 'END is case     *\n");
    printf("* sensitive                                                *\n");
    printf("*                                                          *\n");
    printf("************************************************************\n");
    printf("\n\n\n\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    Heading();
    char str1[20];
    int i =0;
    do
        {

        int count =0;
        do
            {          
            printf("Enter a word in English for the program to return in Pig Latin: ");
            scanf("%s", str1);
            while(str1[count] != '\0')
            ++count;
            if (count>7)
                {
                printf("\n\nInvalid Entry. Please enter a word with no more than 7 letters\n\n");
                count=0;
                }
            }while (count>7);//loop to perform if invalid word is entered
```

// I enter the word greater than 7 letters, it still gives it in pig Latin, instead of prompting for another word. I tried to put a while loop in, but it just gives an infinite loop

```
         //while (count<7)
         //
        printf("\n%s in Pig Latin: ",str1);
        for (i=1;str1[i];++i)
            {
            printf("%c",str1[i]);
            }
        printf("%c",str1[0]);
        printf("ay");
        printf("\n\n\n");
         //}


    }while(str1!= "END");
```

//Also here, it does not end by entering  in END. What am I doing wrong?

```
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are comparing pointers instead of the strings they point to. Take a look at [`strcmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html). Also, if you write two string-literals behind each other, they will be merged by the compiler.

Comment: Well, have you stepped through your code in a debugger, and examined variables, etc.?  That is the first thing to do.  Also read about string comparison in C, because [str1 != "END"] is not going to work.  Those are pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
}while (count>7);//loop to perform if invalid word is entered
```

To

```
}while (count==0);//loop to perform if invalid word is entered
```

And

```
}while(str1!= "END");
```

To

```
}while(strcmp(str1,"END")!=0);
```

Also,don't forget to include `string.h`

Comment: Thank you. I made those changes and I it stil converts END to pig latin instead of just ending the program. Should I add a break in there somewhere?

Comment: Just add `if(strcmp(str,"END")==0)break;` just after your `scanf` and use an infinite loop with something like `for(;;)` or `while(1)`